# HeidiSQl error for MariaDB for wrong syntax

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, heidisql

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near

Here is my SQL:

```
UPDATE product
SET cost_price = db2.supplier.Cost_price
FROM product, db2.supplier WHERE product.SKU = db2.supplier.SKU;
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this join syntax:

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN  db2.supplier ON product.SKU = db2.supplier.SKU
SET product.cost_price = db2.supplier.Cost_price
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `FROM` clause for the `UPDATE` in MariaDB.  Just use `JOIN` instead:

```
UPDATE product p JOIN
       db2.supplier s
       ON p.SKU = s.SKU
    SET p.cost_price = s.Cost_price;
```

Note the use of table aliases and explicit `JOIN` syntax!